# R: Divide columns into various subcolumns at specific chosen points / values

Tags: r

I know this might be simple, however, I searched and couldn't find a clear answer, and as non-experienced user of r, I couldn't develop it myself. 
I simply need to divide a column in a list or data frame into several sub-columns (not necessarily of equal lengths) at certain defined points of specific order or value. I'm dealing with large data so, so there must be a fast function to directly divide the column according to the chosesn points.

To make it clear, I need to make something like:

```
# data frame 
df<- data.frame(cbind("l1"=c(1:20),"l2"=c(21:40)))
# sepration points
pts<- c(4, 11, 17)
# dividing into sub columns
gp1<-df$l1[1:pts[1]]   
gp2<-df$l1[pts[1]:pts[2]]
gp3<-df$l1[pts[2]:pts[3]]
gp4<-df$l1[pts[3]:20]
# combining
res<- list(gp1, gp2, gp3, gp4)

> res
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11

[[3]]
[1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17

[[4]]
[1] 17 18 19 20
```

But without defining the separation points one by one, and without reordering the data on a value basis.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Map` to create the sequence.  Concatenate `1` before the 'pts' and `nrow` at the end of the 'pts' as two separate `vector`s, use that to create sequence of index with `Map` and get the corresponding values of 'l1' column of 'df' based on the sequence

```
Map(function(i, j) df$l1[i:j], c(1, pts), c(pts, nrow(df)))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4

#[[2]]
#[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11

#[[3]]
#[1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17

#[[4]]
#[1] 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: Thank you that actually works fine. 
I just want to add something, if I want to refine that sequence by not repeating a value twice; at the end of a sublist and the beginning of a next, how could I do that?